# How to get WcfFacility and Wcf global exception handling working?

Tags: castle-windsor, castle, wcffacility

I have deployed my service and attached Visual Studio to the process to debug in one Visual Studio instance, and in another I have a client console test application that I run in debug mode, I can see both service methods that I call executed in the debugger, but in the second one where I throw an exception on purpose, I never see the code in ErrorHandlerBehavior called at all.
Is my registration for ErrorHandlerBehavior not correct?

*I wonder if I need to have a behaviour extension in my service configuration for this?*

I based my global exception handling off of the this [example](http://ianfnelson.com/archives/2010/04/09/wcf-global-exception-handling/)

Here is my container registration in my service program main method:

```
container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>(f => f.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.Zero);

    container
        .Register(Component.For<WcfProtoType.IServiceProtoType>()
            .ImplementedBy<WcfProtoType.ProtoTypeService>()
            .Named("ProtoTypeService")
            .AsWcfService( new DefaultServiceModel()
                .AddEndpoints(WcfEndpoint
                    .BoundTo(new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None))
                    .At(baseUrl)

                    ).PublishMetadata(o => o.EnableHttpGet())),Component.For<ServiceBase>().ImplementedBy<MyService>(),
                    Component.For<ErrorHandlerBehavior>().Attribute("scope").Eq(WcfExtensionScope.Services));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the [Castle Windsor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle_Project#Features) source and from what I can tell the EndPointBehavior needs to be registered first like this:

```
container
    .Register(Component.For<ErrorHandlerBehavior>().Attribute("scope").Eq(WcfExtensionScope.Services),
        Component.For<WcfProtoType.IServiceProtoType>()
            .ImplementedBy<WcfProtoType.ProtoTypeService>()
            .Named("ProtoTypeService")
            .AsWcfService( new DefaultServiceModel()
                .AddEndpoints(WcfEndpoint
                    .BoundTo(new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None))
                    .At(baseUrl)
                    ).PublishMetadata(o => o.EnableHttpGet())),Component.For<ServiceBase>().ImplementedBy<MyService>());
```